# "The EntityReference object could not be serialized" when serializing from an ASP.NET Web Site, but works OK on an ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I have an Entity Framework data model.  Part of the model is a Customer entity.  The web service provides a method to get a customer, and to receive an updated version of this customer to be persisted.

To test this, I created a new ASP.NET web *Application*, (Solution > Add > New Project > ASP.NET Web Application), then added a reference to my service reference using the standard Add Service Reference dialog.  I then call the service using the following code:

```
var client = new CustomerServiceClient();
var customer = client.GetCustomerByID(18); // get it
customer.LimitDown = 100; // change it
client.SaveCustomer(customer); // persist it
```

Everything works as expected.

Now, I do exactly the same thing, but this time with as ASP.NET Web *Site* (Solution > Add > New Web Site > ASP.NET Web Site).  I add the reference in a similar fashion and copy and paste the code above into the new site.  But now I get the following exception thrown on the 4th line:

> **System.InvalidOperationException The
>   EntityReference object could not be
>   serialized. This type of object cannot
>   be serialized when the
>   RelationshipManager belongs to an
>   entity object that does not implement
>   IEntityWithRelationships.**
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 2474:         Line 2475:
>   public
>   SkyWalkerCustomerService.OperationResult
>   SaveCustomer(SkyWalkerCustomerService.Customer
>   customer) { Line 2476:
>   return
>   base.Channel.SaveCustomer(customer);
>   Line 2477:        } Line 2478:    }
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9475203
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +345
>   SkyWalkerCustomerService.ICustomerService.SaveCustomer(Customer
>   customer) +0
>   SkyWalkerCustomerService.CustomerServiceClient.SaveCustomer(Customer
>   customer) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30128\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\testsite2\dd2bcf8d\f95604ff\App_WebReferences.fz4h7x7l.0.cs:2476
>   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Mike\Documents\Repositories\UWC\SkyWalker\TestSite2\Default.aspx.cs:17
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +61    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1966

Googling for this error returns very little.  Why doesn't this work?

I guess one answer would be to use a web application instead of a web site, but I have an large existing site to which I need to add the service reference, and I'd rather not convert it.

Comment: Have you checked in your Service Reference configuration to make sure that you are re-using the reference assembly library? This error may be caused by the difference in the Customer object generated from the MetatData of the Service Reference and not the "real" Customer object (ie. the entity model object).

Comment: By default the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" box is checked, and I didn't change this in my reference.  BUT, the assembly containing my EF customer object is not shared anyway - it lives on the server, and I only want my client to be aware of the WCF service, not the EF assembly.

And even if that was the problem, it wouldn't answer the question - why does this work from a web app, but not a web site?

I even tried copying the whole Service References folder from the working app to the non working site, and the error STILL remained.  This is insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary workaround - I changed the .NET Framework version of the web site to 3.5, and now it works correctly.  This is fine for my project, but I'd like to know for future reference why the original problem occurred.

Comment: i have the same problem. if the object i am sending to WCF does not contain any relations... everything works fine... but if has a property referring to another object, the same exception occurs. unlike you, i cannot change the framework version to 3.4!

Answer (score 1):

## Cause

The old version Entity Framework was using EntityObject, EntityReference, etc. WCF cannot serialize if related entities are returned together.

Say, if the WCF method returns a customer with the purchased items, it will fail.

## Fix

When we add service reference to the WCF endpoint that uses old Entity Framework, in **Data Type**, do not select **Reuse types in all referenced assemblies**. But choose **Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies** and make sure `System.Data.Entity` is not selected.

[image]